# Browser-based software to configure as a router

Tags: networking, internet, software-recommendation, software-compatibility

Was just wondering this when trying to configure an RPi as a router, is there a software that you can install on your pi to be able to configure the port forwarding, DHCP, etc by accessing the local address like http://192.168.0.1  in your browser, just like router firmware do?

I couldn't find anything on Google about this (might be searching the wrong term) and I understand that chromium security probably didn't allow to modify system files, but there's always someone who figures out how to do the impossible

Comment: check this out .... https://openwrt.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi is made for education and to learn how hardware and software works. It is not intended to use it point and click for specific use cases. So I worry that you will not find something for your needs just working out of the box. But you are invited to program it ;-)

It may be possible that you find some images made for a router with a Raspberry Pi. I made a quick search on google with [raspberry pi router distro](https://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry+pi+router+distro) and for example found this: [Raspberry Pi - Wifi Router Project](https://ronnyvdbr.github.io/). But this seems to be outdated because of using old hardware and software. And yes, you should also look at the suggestion from *@jsotola* he has made in his comment.